# GraphQL: Error when resolving promises during file upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, promise, graphql

So I've been working with GraphQL uploads, and before stating my problem here's an overview for the tech stack that I am using:

Backend: Mongoose, Express, Apollo, GraphQL

Frontend: VueJS, Apollo, GraphQL

I'm using [Apollo Upload Client](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) to send the *Upload* files to the server side from the client. Since I am sending a list of files type *scalar Upload* from the client, I am receiving a list of promises that need to be resolved. On using *Promise.all()* I am getting the following error (which, weirdly, I wasn't getting before and I don't know why). If I upload more than one file, the first file just gets lost somewhere and the second file uploads.... But this isn't all the time. Sometimes it doesn't happen. Maybe I am not resolving or catering to the promises properly. Note that I also have to save the file name in MongoDB through Mongoose

```
    { BadRequestError: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.
     at IncomingMessage.request.once (F:\repos\pushbox\node_modules\graphql-upload\lib\processRequest.js:245:35)
     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:197:13)
     at resOnFinish (_http_server.js:583:7)
     at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:202:15)
     at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:683:10)
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9)
   message: 'Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.',
   expose: true,
   statusCode: 499,
   status: 499 }
```

I have an HTML file input tag that takes multiple files and the mutation I use is:

```
async uploadFiles() {
  // Check if input tag is empty
  if (this.files.length === 0) {
    this.uploadErrorAlert = true;
    return;
  }

  // Mutation
  this.isUploading = true;
  await this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: UPLOAD_FILES,
    variables: {
      files: this.files,
      id: this.selectedCard.id,
    },
  })
    .then(() => {
    // clear files from the input tag
      this.files = '';
      this.$refs.selectedFiles.value = '';
      this.isUploading = false;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
},
```

And finally, the resolver on the server is:

```
/**
 * Uploads files sent on disk and saves
 * the file names in the DB
 *
 * @param {Object} attachments - List of files for a card
 *
 * @return {Boolean} - true if upload is
 * successful
 */
uploadFiles: async (_, attachments, { controllers }) => {
  Promise.all(attachments.files.map(async (file) => {
    const { createReadStream, filename } = await file;
    const stream = createReadStream();

    /**
     * We need unique names for every file being uploaded,
     * so we use the ID generated by MongoDB and concat it
     * to the filename sent by the user.
     *
     * Therefore we instantiate an attachment object to get an ID
     */
    const attachment = await controllers.attachment.add({ id: attachments.id, file: '' });
    const newFileName = `${attachment.id}_${filename}`;
    const path = `${process.env.UPLOAD_DIR}/${newFileName}`;

    await controllers.attachment.update({
      id: attachment.id,
      file: newFileName,
    });

    console.log(`reached for ${path}`);
    // Attempting to save file in server
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => stream
      .pipe(createWriteStream(path))
      .on('finish', () => resolve())
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('dude?');
        if (stream.truncated) {
          // Delete the truncated file
          unlinkSync(path);
        }
        reject(error);
      }));
  })).then(() => {
    pubsub.publish(ATTACHMENTS_ADDED, { attachmentsChanged: controllers.attachment.getAll() });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
},
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think there could be an issue how you send the file to backend. Usually to upload file and send it to backend, you must use formData object. You have to loop through each files and append it as property. const fd = new FormData(); this.files.forEach((file) => { fd.append(‘files’, file)}

Comment: So I just tried that, and I am receiving nothing on the backend. When I send it without formData i.e. simply send **this.files**, then I receive the files.

console for formData in Backend: `{ id: '5c8b7b5959fa58d85041ba34', files: [ {} ] }`

console for this.files in Backend: `{ id: '5c8b7b5959fa58d85041ba34',
  files:
   [ Promise { [Object] },
     Promise { [Object] },
     Promise { [Object] } ] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I don't know how I missed [this issue](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/149) here, but this right there is the solution! The issue is on the module's, that I am using, github issue forum.

So the problem is solved by using `await` before the `Promise.all()` function. So now the code inside the `uploadFiles` resolver looks like:

```
await Promise.all(attachments.files.map(async (file) => {
    const { createReadStream, filename } = await file;
    const stream = createReadStream();

    /**
     * We need unique names for every file being uploaded,
     * so we use the ID generated by MongoDB and concat it
     * to the filename sent by the user.
     *
     * Therefore we instantiate an attachment object to get an ID
     */
    const attachment = await controllers.attachment.add({ id: attachments.id, file: '' });
    const newFileName = `${attachment.id}_${filename}`;
    const path = `${process.env.UPLOAD_DIR}/${newFileName}`;

    await controllers.attachment.update({
      id: attachment.id,
      file: newFileName,
    });

    console.log(`reached for ${path}`);
    // Attempting to save file in server
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => stream
      .pipe(createWriteStream(path))
      .on('finish', () => resolve())
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.log('dude?');
        if (stream.truncated) {
          // Delete the truncated file
          unlinkSync(path);
        }
        reject(error);
      }));
  })).then(() => {
    pubsub.publish(ATTACHMENTS_ADDED, { attachmentsChanged: controllers.attachment.getAll() });
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```