# Graphql "Network Error : Failed to Fetch" when upload images by taking image from direct camera using Oppo

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have a problem when upload images by taking direct from OPPO camera. I tried this from other smartphone is working as expected.

This is my code

```
const form = new FormData();
function processImages() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        images.forEach(async (image, index, array) => {
          try {
            const data = await getBufferFromStreams(image);
            form.append('images', data.fileBuffer, data.filename);
            if (index === array.length - 1) {
              resolve(true);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      });
    }
const success = await processImages();
const response = await this.post(`${url}`, form, {});
```

```
export const getBufferFromStreams = async (file) => {
  
    if (!file) {
        return new Error('file is undefined');
    }
    const { stream, filename } = await file;
    const chunks = [];
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        stream.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
        stream.on('end', () => {
            resolve({ fileBuffer: Buffer.concat(chunks), filename });
        });
    });
};
```

I always get error "Network Error: Failed to Fetch" when uploading images when taking picture from camera only on OPPO smartphone.

Do you have encounter same issues and solved ?

Comment: many images .. promise.all ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/55257149/6124657